# How to handle linked models?

Tags: database, postgresql, go

I have two models, using Go 1.19:

```golang
type User struct {
    Name string
    ID   int
}

type Order struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
    User *User
    // or
    UserID int
}
```

Of course, the database `orders table` has a foreign key to the `users table` via `user_id`.

Probably in different situations I have to use one of these models. When exactly?
Mb only `user_id` in DTO models, the `user` in responses from the server?

I will be glad for any information :)

Comment: Please clarify the situation. What do you want to achieve. About which situations you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your purpose. As usual, you have to use *id* when a table to include has meta info about your entity (often it's tables with a lot of rows and so heavy), therefore it will be better to use id, otherwise if it's table which describe some fields in initial table, you can use full entity.